# Solving $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^2+1}dx$ using Taylor series

Tags: definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

I know that $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (x+1)}{x^2+1}dx$ is a well-known integral and there are many ways of computing it, including substitutions $x=\tan t$, $x = \frac{1-t}{1+t}$ or differentiating the parametrized integral $I(t) = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(tx+1)}{x^2+1}dx$. I am interested in **whether my solution attempt can be finalized**.
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^2+1}dx = \int_0^1\ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^ix^{i+1}}{i+1}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-x^2)^jdx$$
Here I just rewrote $\ln(x+1)$ and $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ to their Taylor series, which obviously converge to the needed functions since $x\in[0; 1]$. Now I withdraw everything that does not contain $x$ behind the integral sign and compute the simple $\int_0^1 x^n = \frac{1}{n+1}$ integral:
$$=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{i+1}\int_0^1x^{2j+i+1}dx = \sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{(i+1)(2j+i+2)}$$
I can now part the fraction in two, since $\frac{1}{(i+1)(2j+i+2)}=\frac{1}{2j+1}(\frac{1}{i+1}-\frac{1}{2j+i+2})$, so I have:
$$=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^i}{i+1}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1} - \sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{(2j+1)(2j+i+2)}$$
And by writing Taylor series for $\ln2$ and $\arctan1=\frac{\pi}{4}$ I get:
$$=\ln 2\cdot\frac{\pi}{4} - \sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{(2j+1)(2j+i+2)}$$
**That's where the problem starts.** If we knew the value of our integral, which is $\frac{\pi}{8}\ln2$, we would automatically deduce that:
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{(i+1)(2j+i+2)} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{(2j+1)(2j+i+2)} \textbf{(*)}$$
And vice versa, if we could prove the above equality independently of $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^2+1}=\frac{\pi}{8}\ln 2$, we would automatically conclude that 
$$I=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2 - I,$$
where I is equally our integral and both of the sums **(*)**. And we're done as then $I=\frac{\pi}{8}\ln 2$.

So any help in proving **(*)** would be appreciated, as well as showing other ways to use Taylor series in this problem.

Comment: You have to be careful with double sums that don't converge absolutely.  Does $\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty$ mean $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty$ or $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^\infty$?  They might not be the same.

Comment: @RobertIsrael It's $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty$ and the order of sums is never changed. I will edit the question.